# Inner product defined by summation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that $V$ is a finite dimension space over C and $(u_1,...,u_n)$ is a basis for $V$. Show that $\langle\,,\rangle$ : $V × V → C,$ defined by $\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_iu_i\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\overline {b_i}$

I tried to show the 4 properties of an inner product:
for additivity: $\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i+\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_iu_i,\sum_{i=1}^{n} b_iu_i\rangle$ = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (a+c)_i\overline {b_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\overline {b_i}+\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i\overline {b_i} = \langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_iu_i\rangle +\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} c_iu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} b_iu_i\rangle$

Then for homogeneity and conjugate symmetry, it's the same way as above, it's just properties of summations and scalars

For positivity and defineness, $\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\overline {a_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|^2 \geq0$
and if  $\langle\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i, \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i\rangle = 0, \sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|^2 =0$ and since $|a_i|^2 \geq0$ , $a_i=0$ and each  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iu_i =0$

My question is, is my outline correct? If so, why did my proof did not mention anything about a basis and linear independence which is mentioned in the assumption? Where should those conditions about a basis appear in the proof?

Answer (score 3):

In your proof you assumed any vector can be written uniquely as $\sum a_i u_i$. For these you need the properties of a basis.

Answer (score 2):

Those conditions were used to make $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ a well-defined function. More concrete: as $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ is a basis for $V$, the function $\phi : \mathbb C^n \to V$ given by $\phi(a_1,\dots,a_n) = a_1u_1 + \cdots + a_nu_n$ is a linear isomorphism (why?) and then we define $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle : V \times V \to \mathbb C$ by $\langle v_1,v_2 \rangle = \langle \phi^{-1}(v_1),\phi^{-1}(v_2) \rangle_{\mathbb C^n}$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_{\mathbb C^n}$ is the standard inner product in $\mathbb C^n$.